# .ini file automatically downloaded, malware?

Tags: downloading, malware

My phone is LG G2 (D802).
My phone downloaded a .ini file which is currently located under `Downloads > sav_amd_dir > md.ini`. The download happened automatically in the background while I was playing a game (No Limits). It gets weirder; the contents of the .ini file are full of apps names that are in the play store ([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/5HWGkMJT)).

What could this be for? Ads? And how does a phone download a file automatically without my permission?

Comment: Is this the game you're playing: [Need For Speed No Limits](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ea.game.nfs14_row)? The app has permission to access external storage and internet, so it's possible to download that without you knowing it. As for the purpose, I can only guess for ads...

Comment: Yes that's the game. I guessed it's for ads as well. Thanks for a reply.